# Safari text and divs juggled and out of place during jquery slide out

Tags: jquery, css, safari, browser-bugs

It is a strange bug and the site works perfectly in all browsers expect for this issue in Safari  (testing in version 5.1.7 ) .  Here is the link to my site.

http://www.enrista.co.za/new-swap/?page_id=1669

If you click on the plus symbol to open up the widget area, you can see the issue I am talking about. The text and the divs go out of place until a resize event on the window which gets it normal. I also noticed that the issue occurs only with my news letter and social media widgets. I tried out other widgets and had it work normally. Would appreciate some assistance here, disappointed with this bug after months of hard work building a theme.

Comment: Found a solution. slideToggle() was causing the issue. Added a wrapper to the div that was toggled and used a custom slidefadeToggle function. A weird bug, because it was working great in all other browsers and of all I thought safari would be the least of my worries.  Thanks to everyone who took time to look into the issue

Comment: please, write that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: +1 in hopes of this being accepted as the answer.